# Dynamic Pivot List in Linq C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-web-api, pivot

I have three table Product, Location, StockLocation. I want to show data like that where location show as column and it should be dynamic:

[image]

I want to populate data in my asp.net core API application using entity framework core and show it in my angular 7 project. If it possible in any opensource client-side library please suggest to me .

SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE [Product](
    [ProductId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SalesPrice] [decimal](18, 0) NULL
) 
GO


CREATE TABLE [Location](
    [LocationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    [LocationName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)

GO
CREATE TABLE [StockLocation](
    [StockId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StockProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StockLocationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotalQuantity] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StockLocation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StockId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StockLocation]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StockLocation_Location] FOREIGN KEY([StockLocationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([LocationId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StockLocation] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_StockLocation_Location]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StockLocation]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_StockLocation_Product] FOREIGN KEY([StockProductId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([ProductId])
GO


------------ Data-------

INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([ProductName], [Description], [Code], [SalesPrice]) VALUES ( N'Ravtop', N'M3 Plus Smart Bracelet Heart Rate Blood Pressure Health Waterproof Smart Watch M3 Pro Bluetooth ', N'R200154', CAST(2250 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([ProductName], [Description], [Code], [SalesPrice]) VALUES ( N'B57 Water Proof', N'B57 Smart watches Waterproof Sports for iphone phone Smartwatch Heart Rate Monitor Blood Pressure Functions For Women men kid', N'B570021', CAST(1850 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([ProductName], [Description], [Code], [SalesPrice]) VALUES ( N'CHYCET', N'2019 Bluetooth Smart Watch Men Blood Pressure Round Smartwatch Women Watch Waterproof Sport', N'C220172', CAST(2400 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([ProductName], [Description], [Code], [SalesPrice]) VALUES ( N'Kaihai H 69', N'KAIHAI H69 ECG PPG SpO2 HRV fitness health smart watch men electronic blood pressure measurement Heart rate monitor smartwatch', N'KHSW69', CAST(2800 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([ProductName], [Description], [Code], [SalesPrice]) VALUES ( N'Lempo IP67', N'LEMFO Smart Watch Women OTA Update IP67 Waterproof Blood Pressure Heart Rate Call Message Reminder for Sports Watch', N'L5800AD', CAST(2800 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product] ([ProductName], [Description], [Code], [SalesPrice]) VALUES ( N'ZGPAX', N'Smart Watch Men Women 1.3 Inch Round Screen Smart Watch Blood Pressure Measurement Oxygen Smartwatch Watch Smart For IOS Andriod', N'2554223', CAST(1120 AS Decimal(18, 0)))
GO

INSERT INTO [Location](LocationName) VALUES ('Head Office')
INSERT INTO [Location](LocationName) VALUES ('Uttara')
INSERT INTO [Location](LocationName) VALUES ('MES')
INSERT INTO [Location](LocationName) VALUES ('Chittagong')
INSERT INTO [Location](LocationName) VALUES ('Rajshahi')
INSERT INTO [Location](LocationName) VALUES ('Sylhet')



INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (1,1,4700)
INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (1,2,4100)
INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (1,3,200)
INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (1,4,400)
INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (1,5,850)
INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (2,1,50)
INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (2,2,520)
INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (2,3,200)
INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (2,5,40)
INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (3,1,412)
INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (3,5,45)
INSERT INTO [StockLocation]([StockProductId],[StockLocationId],[TotalQuantity])VALUES (3,4,34)
```

Comment: Search this site for "dynamic pivot". This has been asked and answered hundreds of times.

Comment: or better, use google to search for "Dynamic pivot", by using "site:stackoverflow.com" in front of your search terms ;)

Comment: Dynamic linq in Entity you wold need to enumerate through the properties in the classes.  It may be easier to return a table with all the columns and then filter the columns dynamically to get only the column you want to display.

Comment: You won't easily be able to dynamic pivot with standard LINQ as anonymous objects are defined at compile time, but you can retrieve your data and put into `DataTable`s and then pivot by creating a new `DataTable`. You could also use a `DynamicObject` but I don't believe they work automatically with asp.net grids.

Comment: how i bind it in POCO? btw mainly i need json to bind data in client-side. thanks all @NetMage

Comment: @ShahidMAB Unless you already know the possible locations and can create a static definition for it, it isn't possible - by definition, a regular class is static and defined at compile time, not run time.

Comment: @NetMage . Location table is dynamic i don't know how many location have that is column will be dynamic

Comment: Then that is why you must use something like `DataTable` that can have columns added at runtime.